# Error could not bind the socket: Cannot assign requested address

Tags: c, sockets, udp, bind, raspbian

I am developing an application that uses datagram sockets for communication. I having a strange problem where the first run of the application always fails on the bind of the first socket with `Cannot assign requested address` but the second time i run the application everything works as expected.

I already checked that the arguments for the `bind()` are correct. Before i set up the socket i am configuring the ip address of the interface with `ioctl()` calls and set it up and running.

I would like to have more details about the reason why he couldn't bind the socket. Are there some log files i could check or something else? I appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: Perhaps the socket is already in use and it needs to be released by the OS before being able to be used in a new `bind()`? Something similar happened to me but only after my programs crashed and did not clean up the resources themselves. Also can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @rdxdk Thank you very much for your suggestion. I do not think it has to do something with the socket being already in use. The problem occures even after a fresh boot of the raspberry pi. I am thinking it has to do something with the interface not being 100% configured at the time the `bind()` is happening. Prehaps the `ioctl()` calls are taking some time.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not occuring when i add a sleep after the `ioctl()` setup process. It seems like the `ioctl()` calls are taking some time to finish hence the error on the bind since the interface is not 100% configured yet with that ip address.

Comment: Can you post the code? Why are you using `ioctl()` in the first place? Have you checked its return value or `errno` for errors? Are you sure the parameters you pass are initialized correctly? Take a look at the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) in case you're forgetting something.

Comment: I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67026638/how-can-i-check-if-an-ioctl-executed) because the `bind()` call is not the problem in this case. I am using `ioctl()` because i need to configure the IP settings of an interface on execution. I posted the code that i wrote on the new question.